# 500 (Internal Server Error) ajax get datatable laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable, laravel-5

I'm using datatable for showing record and using **laravel for backend**
in my localhost its normally show data in datatable. But when I run in homestead, I have an error:

> "500 (Internal Server Error)" in my ajax

here my json data:

```
[{"id":11,"uid":null,"email":"muhghazaliakbar@live.com","username":"muhghazaliakbar","oauth_provider_id":null,"activated":1,"activation_code":null,"activated_at":"2015-05-31 03:54:29","last_login":null,"persist_code":null,"reset_password_code":null,"created_at":"2015-05-31 03:54:29","updated_at":"2015-05-31 03:54:29","deleted_at":null},{"id":12,"uid":null,"email":"nurindahsari@live.com","username":"nurindahsari","oauth_provider_id":null,"activated":1,"activation_code":null,"activated_at":"2015-05-31 13:50:57","last_login":null,"persist_code":null,"reset_password_code":null,"created_at":"2015-05-31 13:50:57","updated_at":"2015-05-31 13:50:57","deleted_at":null},{"id":15,"uid":"974422342576145","email":"tambahkancintadankurangibenci@hotmail.com","username":"tambahkancintadankurangibenci@hotmail.com","oauth_provider_id":1,"activated":1,"activation_code":null,"activated_at":null,"last_login":null,"persist_code":null,"reset_password_code":null,"created_at":"2015-05-31 17:30:13","updated_at":"2015-05-31 17:30:14","deleted_at":null}]
```

and here my script:

```
    var UsersTable = function () {
    var handleRecords = function () {
        var grid = new Datatable();
        var table = $("#frontend_users_table");
        grid.init({
            src: table,
            onSuccess: function (grid) {
                // execute some code after table records loaded
                console.log(grid);
            },
            onError: function (grid) {
                // execute some code on network or other general error
            },
            loadingMessage: 'Loading...',
            dataTable: { // here you can define a typical datatable settings from http://datatables.net/usage/options

                "bStateSave": true, // save datatable state(pagination, sort, etc) in cookie.

                "lengthMenu": [
                    [10, 20, 50, 100, 150, -1],
                    [10, 20, 50, 100, 150, "All"] // change per page values here
                ],
                "pageLength": 10, // default record count per page
                "ajax": {
                    "url": globalUrl + "/users/frontend/all",// ajax source
                    "type": "GET"
                },
                "searchable": true,
                "order": [
                    [1, "asc"]
                ]
            }
        });
    };

    return {

        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function () {

            handleRecords();
        }

    };
} ();
```

Here is my server side code

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["search_users"]) != '') {
        $str = $_REQUEST["search_users"];
        $userData = \PasangJob\Model\Frontend\User::where('username', 'LIKE', '%'.$str.'%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.$str.'%')
                ->get();
    } else {
        $userData = \PasangJob\Model\Frontend\User::get();
        return $userData;
    }
    $iTotalRecords = $userData->count();

    $iDisplayLength = intval($_REQUEST['length']);
    $iDisplayLength = $iDisplayLength < 0 ? $iTotalRecords : $iDisplayLength;
    $iDisplayStart = intval($_REQUEST['start']);
    $sEcho = intval($_REQUEST['draw']);

    $records = array();
    $records["data"] = array();

    $end = $iDisplayStart + $iDisplayLength;
    $end = $end > $iTotalRecords ? $iTotalRecords : $end;

    for($i = $iDisplayStart; $i < $end; $i++) {
        if ($userData[$i]->activated == '1')
        {
            $status = "<span class=\"label label-success label-sm\">Activated<span>";
        } else
        {
            $status = "<span class=\"label label-danger label-sm\">Not Activated<span>";
        }
        $records["data"][] = array(
            $userData[$i]->id,
            $userData[$i]->username,
            $userData[$i]->email,
            $userData[$i]->roles->first()->display_name,
            $status,
            $userData[$i]->last_login,
            "<a id=\"view-user\" href=\"".route('pasangjob.users.frontend.show', $id = $userData[$i]->id)."\" class=\"btn default btn-xs green-stripe\">View</a>"
        );
    }

    $records["draw"] = $sEcho;
    $records["recordsTotal"] = $iTotalRecords;
    $records["recordsFiltered"] = $iTotalRecords;

    return response()->json($records);
```

Comment: A 500 error means the issue is with your server-side code, not JS.

Comment: i test in url get, but result json is good.

Comment: There is good package available for data table. Please check it [here](https://github.com/Chumper/Datatable).

Comment: @AlankarMore im using laravel 5 not laravel 4

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i've updated my post, i added my server side code, please check

Comment: Ok just try to implement it may it works with the Laravel 5 too.

Comment: @AlankarMore i've try but not works.

Comment: [fixed] my fault xD in my server side code

Comment: I would like to higly recommend you to use Input::get() or $request->input() instead of getting your parameters with $_REQUEST

Comment: Ow yeah, i'll fix my code, thanks :)